# Get how many lines in a text, based on the view width not carriage return or line feed (\r\n)

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am implementing a comment system in my website and I need to hide the text after exceeding 5 lines in a view width of 300px and show "**Read more**", I've tried doing so with string length but every character has a different width, for example 500 characters of "**@**" (at sign) in a view width of 300px will have more lines than 500 characters of "**.**" (dot) in a view width of 300px and also the user might use a lot of **carriage return**, after a lot of headache I thought is was impossible, then I've went to YouTube to see if they solved this problem, and obviously they did!

[image: Example]

So my question is how it possible? just guide me in the right direction and I'll do my research.

**NOTE 1**: 300px view width is just an example and can change.

**NOTE 2**: I am using PHP if that matters.

**NOTE 3**: I think JavaScript solutions can be fooled by users, but I am not sure.

**NOTE 4**: The only solution I can think of is using a reference for each character width based on the font in use, and use that to **figure** out how many lines they are in a specific view width, But isn't that too much work since there is a huge number of supported characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably calculate how many lines there will be. It depends on too many factors, like the font, the browser and even the operating system.

Just use css to hide everything after x lines. I put together a quick example:

This class hides everything but the first 5 lines.

```
.truncated {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 6em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then just add a button that removes that class using javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/rmwu4sL1/